# How to create templatized wrapper class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am invoking a function from many places in the project. Only difference is that one of the parameters is of different data types.

I was asked to create a templatized wrapper class. Could someone help me how to do that?

I am invoking the below function from different places. Here when invoking this function, the second parameter (f_strCallid) might be string, int, unsigned long etc.

```
std::shared_ptr<CCallListImpl> CCallListImpl::handleCallCollectionEvents(Events f_eCallEvent, const std::string& f_strCallid)
{
    shared_ptr<CCallListImpl> l_hObj = nullptr;

    return l_hObj;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your specification, it should be something like:

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<CCallListImpl>
CCallListImpl::handleCallCollectionEvents(Events f_eCallEvent, const T& f_strCallid)
{
    shared_ptr<CCallListImpl> l_hObj = nullptr;

    return l_hObj;
}
```